# How the JSON was developed and what was the technology used to development

Tags: json

In our project we start using JSON file, when i start research on What the JSON is and where it comes from, What is the technology they have used, is it only javascript or anyother and which parsing tool they have used,but i didn't get any clear information. If anyone have such reference document and ideas please give me link .

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a data exchange format, like xml, csv...

Even if it's part of JavaScript it's not restricted to JS. JSON can be used in nearly every language and im pretty sure, every good language have a parser implementation in place. json.org lists a overview of projects related to JSON.

As you asked for links to information:

(Complete Overview)
http://json.org/

(Douglas Crockford 'The JSON Saga') https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C-JoyNuQJs

(ECMA Standard that defines JSON) http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf